# Simplify this equation of variables and parameters

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, simplifying-expressions

I am a beginner in Mathematica. Apologies if the question may sound trivial.

I need to implement the following set of equations

$$    \begin{align}
    \beta_1 &\equiv - \frac{3 (\rho_m + p_m)}{H^2 M_*^2} + \frac{\alpha'_B H - (2-\alpha_B) H'}{a H^2}, \\
    \beta_2 &\equiv \alpha_B(1 + \alpha_T) + 2(\alpha_M - \alpha_T), \\
    \beta_3 &\equiv (1 + \alpha_T) \beta_1 + (1 + \alpha_M)\beta_2.
    \end{align}$$

where $a, H, H', M_*, \rho_m$ an $p_m$ are PARAMETERS. The variables are $\alpha_B, \alpha_M, \alpha_T$. Instead, $\alpha_B '$ is the derivative of $\alpha_B$ w.r.t. time, as in fact all the $\alpha$ functions are functions of time. But for my purposes here, I can consider $\alpha_B'$ as well as a parameter. Once I defined this set of equations, I have other two equations

$$    \begin{align}
    \gamma_0 &= \frac{\beta_3}{\beta_1 + \beta_2} \\
    G_0 &= \frac{2(\beta_1 + \beta_2)}{M_*^2[2 \beta_1 + (2 - \alpha_B)\beta_2]}.
    \end{align}$$

If the $\alpha$ are all 0, then $\gamma_0$ must be 1. 
Here is my code:

```
beta1[alphaB_, 
   alphaBprime_] := -3.*(rho + P)/(H^2 Mstar^2) + (alphaBprime*
       H - (2 - alphaB) Hprime)/(a H^2);

beta2[alphaB_, alphaT_, alphaM_] := 
 alphaB*(1. + alphaT) + 2.*(alphaM - alphaT)

beta3[alphaT_, alphaB_, alphaM_, 
  alphaBprime_] := (1. + alphaT)*
   beta1[alphaB, alphaBprime] + (1. + alphaM)*
   beta2[alphaB, alphaT, alphaM]

   gamma0[alphaB_, alphaM_, alphaT_, alphaBprime_] := 
  beta3[alphaT, alphaB, alphaM, 
    alphaBprimo]/(beta1[alphaB, alphaBprime] + 
     beta2[alphaB, alphaT, alphaM]);

G0[alphaK_, alphaB_, alphaM_, alphaT_, alphaBprime_] := 
  2.*(beta1[alphaB, alphaBprime] + 
      beta2[alphaB, alphaT, 
       alphaM])/(Mstar^2*(2.*
         beta1[alphaB, alphaBprime] + (2. - alphaB)*
         beta2[alphaB, alphaT, alphaM]));
Simplify[gamma0[ 0, 0 , 0, 0]]
```

but using this, the output is an expression which is not EXPLICITLY 1, while I would like to see directly from the output that I get 1.

Comment: There are a few undefined parameters in your code: In your definition of `gamma0` you have an `alphaBprimo` (which I assume is a typo for `alphaBprime`), and in your definition of `G0` there's a `Mstar` which is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues here. First, you have a typo in the definition of `gamma0`, where you have `alphaBprimo` instead of `alphaBprime` (you can tell this immediately by the colour of the variables in Mathematica, blue means undefined whereas green is a local function variable).
Second, you are using floating point numbers for your integers, instead of exact numbers. Don't use `1.`, use `1`.

```
beta1[alphaB_, alphaBprime_] := -3*(rho + P)/(H^2 Mstar^2) + (alphaBprime*
       H - (2 - alphaB) Hprime)/(a H^2);

beta2[alphaB_, alphaT_, alphaM_] := 
 alphaB*(1 + alphaT) + 2*(alphaM - alphaT)

beta3[alphaT_, alphaB_, alphaM_, 
  alphaBprime_] := (1 + alphaT)*
   beta1[alphaB, alphaBprime] + (1 + alphaM)*
   beta2[alphaB, alphaT, alphaM]

gamma0[alphaB_, alphaM_, alphaT_, alphaBprime_] := 
  beta3[alphaT, alphaB, alphaM, 
    alphaBprime]/(beta1[alphaB, alphaBprime] + 
     beta2[alphaB, alphaT, alphaM]);

G0[alphaK_, alphaB_, alphaM_, alphaT_, alphaBprime_] := 
  2*(beta1[alphaB, alphaBprime] + 
      beta2[alphaB, alphaT, 
       alphaM])/(Mstar^2*(2*beta1[alphaB, alphaBprime] + (2 - alphaB)*
         beta2[alphaB, alphaT, alphaM]));
Simplify[gamma0[0, 0, 0, 0]]
(* 1 *)
```